# ExpandableListView - group rows do not react on clicks

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I had an `ExpandableListView` with a `CheckedTextView` as grouprow View. But I needed to reduce spacing between groups so I've put it inside a `LinearLayout`. The List does not expand since then, just no reaction on clicks. Any ideas? Code goes below

grouprow.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/holder"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
<CheckedTextView 

android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="-13dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-13dp"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="60sp"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

getting the group view:

```
       @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
    }
    LinearLayout holder = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    CheckedTextView txtGr = (CheckedTextView)    holder.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtGr.setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
    txtGr.setChecked(isExpanded);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
            "uww.otf");
    txtGr.setTypeface(font);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by setting both the `LinearLayout` and the `CheckedTextView` to non-clickable